# How to select the video strips at the playhead through python?

Tags: python, video-sequence-editor

I need to select the strips at the playhead through python, so I can do different things, like delete and close the gap.

I've posted an image to show that the active clip might be somewhere else, and there might be multiple strips where the playhead is.

I know how to get the current frame
bpy.context.scene.frame_current

and I can find
bpy.context.scene.active_clip

but i can't see any options to select the playhead strips.

[image]

Comment: You can find the operator in this add-on(and in the select menu): https://github.com/tin2tin/Sequence_Editing/raw/main/space_sequencer.zip
It's part of the Sequence Editing workspace: https://github.com/tin2tin/Sequence_Editing

Comment: Btw. I've tried numerous times to submit patches which adds this imo crucial function, and once it was even committed, but then a dev reverted the patch: https://developer.blender.org/D7679 For some odd reason this dev is insisting that this should not be in the sequnecer...

Comment: Thank you @tintwotin! And cool project you have there, I didn't know about it until now. That's silly, of course that's necessary.

Comment: Actually, if all of the strips are like in your image you can select liked(in time) by ctrl+mouse click. bpy.ops.sequencer.select(wait_to_deselect_others=False, mouse_x=310, mouse_y=203, linked_time=True, side_of_frame=True)